# logback - no applicable action for [root]

Tags: logback

i just started with Java and i'm trying to configure the logging via logback.

The logging does not work, instead i get an an error in the console:

```
-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:29 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][root]]
```

so no appender is found:

```
-WARN in Logger[Test01] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [Test01].
```

My code is very simple:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainClass.class);
        log.debug("test");    }
}
```

Complete console output when running looks like this:

```
08:41:43,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
08:41:43,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
08:41:43,047 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/klein/IdeaProjects/Maven01ArtifactId/target/classes/logback.xml]
08:41:43,196 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
08:41:43,199 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
08:41:43,209 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
08:41:43,235 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:29 - no applicable action for [root], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][root]]
08:41:43,235 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:41 - no applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][root][appender-ref]]
08:41:43,235 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
08:41:43,235 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@78e94dcf - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
08:41:43,235 |-WARN in Logger[Test01] - No appenders present in context [default] for logger [Test01].
```

I'm using IntelliJ Community 2018.3 and started a project with Maven. logback.xml and pom.xml are below.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

logback.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </root>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.25</slf4jVersion>
        <logbackVersion>1.2.3</logbackVersion>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logbackVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logbackVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

In logback.xml, you put the `<root>` section inside the `<appender>` section.
Your logback.xml should be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```